# Which one is better database design

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm building a database that contain logs for jobs

I'm now having this database :

Jobs :

```
id || job_name || etc...
```

job log which contain the status data

```
id || job_id || etc.. || job_status_id
```

to get the current job status i depend on last inserted status but this leading to harder queries

I was thinking, if I do this:
Jobs:

```
id || job_name || etc...  || job_status_id
```

but this will lead to repeat data as job_status_id is already stored

so adding job_status_id to jobs table instead of depending on last inserted status  to get current job status 
Is this what is more efficient (does it have any other benefits)? Or should I just stick to what I have already?

Comment: depend on what like application need I guess

Comment: Both solutions are viable. If you add the last `job_status_id` to the `Jobs` then it's easier and faster to do selects from it later (no jons and complicated SQL logic. **But** you have to ensure that that last status is always correct i.e. implement triggers on job_logs that will update it. Inserts and updates will be a little slower then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your need. If it's leading to more complex queries to get the last inserted status then it makes sense to have a Job Status ID. I would go with the ID because if you need to query off of that field you can throw an index on it if it becomes an issue where I'm sure it sounds like the last inserted status calculates the job status. So have the initial insert or update create the job status so you don't need to calculate it every time. Again, if that's what you need is performance then that's the better way to go over deriving it. Storage is cheap, plus we're talking about an integer so it's nothing at all. Unless we're talking the difference between 20ms here. ;)